# IE9 Input and Select zoom issue using EM unit

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, font-size

I have a page, all styles are authored using `em` unit for sizing. I am facing a strange issue in IE9.

I have a requirement to have custom zoom buttons. By clicking on that button, I am increasing the `font-size` of body. Eg from `1em to 2em` and all child elements gets the higher inheritance and zoom is applied.

But whenever zoom is applied, texts are hidden in `SELECT` and `INPUT` fields. This gets fixed as soon as you interact with that element - that is as soon as you focus the cursor on that element, everything looks okay.

See this picture:

[image]

What could be the issue? How I might fix it?

**Please note**, I tried making a JS fiddle, but no success on reproducing the issue. A clone of what I have in real app can be seen here: http://shekhardesigner.github.io/IE9-EM-Sizing-ZOOM-Issue/

Comment: I cant see any select elements in your example? Also, for me in IE9- the other inputs seem to 'zoom' OK

Comment: This happens in both INPUT and SELECT.

Comment: As noted, I cant see the effect you mention for either

Comment: I have mentioned it, I cant reproduce the issue on a simpler page. May be this can be answered if someone has experienced it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have correct Standard Doctype Rendering, also you could add 
"`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`" inside the head tag. It helps to display the webpage in edge mode, which is the highest standards mode supported by Internet Explorer, from Internet Explorer 6 through IE11.